# SQL insert new row only if two columns(ids) do not exist in pair previously

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Table_A:

```
id | user_id | stage_id | create_date
```

Table_B:

```
id | stage_id | template_id | name | description | create_date
```

I'm saving data to these via a form on a page with ajax calls. My problem is I only want to insert a new row into Table_A if the stage_id user_id pairing is unique.

example of what I don't want, Table_A:

```
 id    user_id   stage_id   create_date
0129 |  24321  |  3202393 | 01/12/12
0129 |  39234  |  3202393 | 01/12/12
2329 |  39234  |  3202393 | 01/14/12
3459 |  39234  |  3202393 | 01/15/12
```

^ This is what I don't want to happen, any good way to handle this?

it should be:

```
 id    user_id   stage_id   create_date
0129 |  24321  |  3202393 | 01/12/12
0129 |  39234  |  3202393 | 01/12/12
```

Executing queries via php class as in this oversimplified example:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO Table_A ('.
            'id, '.
            'user_id, '.
            'stage_id, '.
            'create_date '.
            ') OUTPUT inserted.id '.
            'VALUES ('.
                'newid(), '.
                '%s, '.
                '%s, '.
                'getdate()'.
        ')';

$this->db->Execute($query);
```

Probably missing something stupid, but I thought someone may be able to push me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Does Table_B play a role in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just query your table to see if a value already exists for your stage_id, user_id pair.

so something like:

```
if not exists (select * from table_A where user_id = @myUserID and stage_id = @myStageID)
begin
insert into ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do it in the database, you can use the UNIQUE constraint in sql-server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx